# Does ftransform() in GLSL 1.20 do the same thing as mat3(gbufferModelViewInverse) * (gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal)?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, minecraft, vertex-shader

I saw the ftransform() function while learning about Minecraft shaders.

```
gl_Position = ftransform(); 
TexCoords = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st;
```

Here is an example use in a Vertex Shader. (.vsh file) The docs for GLSL 1.20 does not give details at all about its implementation.

Does the above code do the same thing as the following:

```
gl_Position = mat3(gbufferModelViewInverse) * (gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal); 
TexCoords = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st;
```

Comment: Why would transforming the *normal* by the normal matrix be part of the *position* transformation? And why would a standard GL command be dependent on a user-defined variable like `gbufferModelViewInverse`?

Comment: I thought  `gbufferModelViewInverse` was provided by the GLSL Language. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the specification [The OpenGL® Shading Language, Version 4.60 - 8.5. Geometric Functions](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#geometric-functions):

> Available only when using the compatibility profile. For core OpenGL, use invariant.
> For vertex shaders only. This function will ensure that the incoming vertex value will be transformed in a way that produces exactly the same result as would be produced by OpenGL’s fixed functionality transform. It is intended to be used to compute `gl_Position`

So `ftransform()` does the same as:

```c
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```